# Transferring 4D array from Python to Jython

Tags: java, python, numpy, jython

My question is basically the title: I have a number of large numpy arrays that I want to port to a Java application, eventually. The only way I see myself doing this is by first transferring this data to Jython. However, I am not sure how to do this as numpy doesn't exist in Jython.

Comment: numpy in jython http://jyni.org/

Comment: "numpy arrays that I want to port to a Java application" i do not get it ... what do you want to "port"? the data? why not writing the data to a file and parsing it in java?

Comment: I'll check out jyni.

Yes. It is the data that I want to port. I suppose that I could dump all the numbers to a file and use a Scanner to read them all in and create the arrays that way.

Comment: It seems jyni is not ready to run numpy yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Python will easily let you serialize your data to files in whatever format you want in 3 lines of code. What format your java application can read from?

If you don't want to write data to disk, or even can't duplicate the in-memory data to pass to other process one thing to check is cap'n'proto -https://capnproto.org/

One way of serializing the arrays as json encoded data files is simply:

```
 import json
 json.dump(myarray.tolist(), open("myfile.json", "wt"))
```

If you Java side can read json, that is all you need.